My NextJs app can't find my home page, but others work. Why is this?
I have a NextJs app running on a VPS I have with GoDaddy. When I go to my website, I can find other pages manually (like this: domainname.com/specific_page). However, my home page gives me a NextJs 404 page. I am using the app router, so my main page.tsx is inside the app directory as usual. It's important to note that in a local environment on my laptop, this all works perfectly fine, and as far as I can tell its setup correctly. Interestingly, when I use curl, it returns the html for the home page... so it isn't like its nonexistent. My suspicion is that its something to do with the server configuration, but I am not experienced enough to figure this out.
Anyone have any ideas? I would be grateful for any guidance here as I am not experienced with these things at all. Thanks in advance for any kind people's help, and I'll post whatever files or code people need.
